# Arrange entites added to GAE by newest first when added?

Tags: java, android, database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I created a google app engine client using eclipse and the android demo google hands out. I Created the back end and a few models. When I add an entities from android to my database on GAE it orders it by date not by newest created first. The key it just the current date and tie on android. Im not sure how to work with the back end, as google created it for me in my project. Is there a fast change I can make to it so instead or it ordering it by data when I add an item it will just keep the newest listings on top?

Edited question, this is my endpoint class Google generated for me. How can I modify it to receive the newest added entities first?

```
@Api(name = "quotesendpoint", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain =     "projectquotes.com"           ownerName = "projectquotes.com", packagePath = ""))
 public class quotesEndpoint {

/**
 * This method lists all the entities inserted in datastore.
 * It uses HTTP GET method and paging support.
 *
 * @return A CollectionResponse class containing the list of all entities
 * persisted and a cursor to the next page.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
@ApiMethod(name = "listquotes")
public CollectionResponse<quotes> listquotes(
        @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
        @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {

 EntityManager mgr = null;
Cursor cursor = null;
List<quotes> execute = null;

try {
    mgr = getEntityManager();
    Query query = mgr.createQuery("select from quotes as quotes");
    if (cursorString != null && cursorString != "") {
        cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
        query.setHint(JPACursorHelper.CURSOR_HINT, cursor);
   }

    if (limit != null) {
        query.setFirstResult(0);
    query.setMaxResults(limit);
}

execute = (List<quotes>) query.getResultList();
cursor = JPACursorHelper.getCursor(execute);
if (cursor != null)
    cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();

// Tight loop for fetching all entities from datastore and accomodate
// for lazy fetch.
for (quotes obj : execute)
    ;
} finally {
    mgr.close();
}

return CollectionResponse.<quotes> builder().setItems(execute)
        .setNextPageToken(cursorString).build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order you see in datastore viewer in GAE is not significant as it is just a display of the current data in your datastore and shown in the increasing order of entity id(if using auto id). This could coincidentally also have an increasing order of date. You cannot modify this display pattern.

What matters is the order seen by your queries and this is determined by indexes. So if you need to get your entities in the descending order of date, then if your date entry is left as indexed, GAE will be automatically having an index for date. You just need to query your entities by specifying a descending sort order on the date property.

EDIT:
Based on the code added, below modifications should be done to query the entities in descending order of date.

1, Add a new date property in your entity:

```
private Date entrydate;
```

2, While creating an entity, add the current date to this property

```
yourentity.setEntryDate(new Date())
```

3, While querying, set ordering based on descending order of date

```
query.setOrdering("entrydate desc");
```

Comment: I edited my question for you. I feel as if I'm close to getting this to work. There is my generated endpoint class. Can I modify it to send me the newest created entities first?

Comment: Ohh and the reason I ask like this is because I receive my entities as they appear on gae.

Comment: updated the answer to give some indications, regarding what to do. check the documentation to verify exact steps

Comment: great answer, you are getting me on the right track. set entry data is not a method in query... maybe i should modify Query query = entityManager.createQuery();  to send it back by newest date?